# Ubuntu14.04 installed but no GUI

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, gui

I have *windows 7 64 bit* on my system, I installed ubuntu 14.04 with help of daemon tools. everything runs smoothly and while booting of ubuntu , i seen a  `/tmp directory issue` which  ignore with`I`

now I am getting only tty1 to tty6 screen , no GUI. I tried to install unitiy using

`sudo apt-get`

but gives error unable to `mkdir /var ..` ( I don't remember complete sentence )

I found that /root doesn't have write permission as well as /var directory

Please help me to enable/install GUI screen.

what i think :

I have to mount that image which may be essential to complete some missing things.

Comment: No gui? Login works? Try startx Maybe try live version first,install from gui live,
install mount point and swap / /swap.

Comment: Far too vague to give you an acceptable answer. Please include the exact messages and error messages.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu with deamon tools ? Have you installed in a VM ?

Comment: @hatterman no. i installed on other partition, from Windows, I can see all ubuntu distribution in E drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution

change `ro` to `rw` and add `nomodeset` quite splash while editing on ubuntu grub while booting